# Vectorize 2d-array access (GCC)

Tags: arrays, gcc, vector, vectorization, simd

I understand the basic ideas of vectorization. I am thinking transform one of my programs into to the vectorized version. But it seems complicated.

There is a table (2d-array) `table[M][N]`, and two vectors `X[1..4]` and `Y[1..4]`. Can I do operations as below? Any thoughts?

```
X[1..4] = table[X[1..4]][Y[1..4]]
```

(sequential version: `X[i] = table[X[i]][Y[i]]`)

In another word, can the following loop be vectorized?

```
    for(k=0; k<4; k++) {
        tmp1 = X[k];
        tmp2 = Y[k];
        X[k] = table[tmp1][tmp2];
    }
```

Note: **`X[]` always contains distinct values**.

Currently, it is implemented in C Language.

Comment: Probably not, but it depends on the type of X and the values of M and N (it *might* just be doable for small values of M, N).

Comment: I don't quite see how it makes sense to iterate over both the x and y dimension at once, but maybe you are solving some artificial math problem.

Comment: Which vector instruction set?

Comment: @harold I am using GCC (tried version 4.8, 4.9, 5)

Answer (score 2):

1) Technically, hayesti has answered your question (inserts/hoirzontal instructions on SSE/AVX of vgather on AVX2 will make it possible). But note also that both GCC4.9 and ICC will vectorize given code snippet (so no any need for intrinsics/hand-coding for truely random access), although for GCC you'll probably need #pragma omp simd, and you may also need -vec-threshold0 for ICC on SSE machines.

2) **Practically,** if you have to vectorize given code "as is", it will never be very good speed-up, because you need to "ammortize" big overhead (latency) of *vgather* or *vinsert*-s with sufficient vector computation (which you don't have in your example) to make vectorization *"profitable"*. And no need to say that you will also need appropriate loop trip counts, etc.

I just checked static cost model estimation for vectorized version of your code using one of fresh ICC compilers' [report](https://software.intel.com/en%C2%ADus/videos/getting-%20the%C2%ADmost%C2%ADout%C2%ADof%C2%ADthe%C2%ADintel%C2%ADcompiler%C2%ADwith%C2%ADnew%C2%ADoptimization%C2%ADreports) (or "[Intel Vectorization Advisor](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/vectorization-advisor-faq)") outputs.

- For **SSE** code generation it was: **0.5x** (i.e. slowdown)
- For **AVX** code generation it was: **1.1x** speed-up (as upper bound)
- For **AVX2** code generation it was: **1.3x - 1.4x** speed-up (as upper bound).

Now, remember that all these speed-ups are *optimistic* upper bounds provided by very nice optimizing compiler (I don't know if GCC will be better or worse). Depending on your indices layouts, matrix size, and overall bandwidth-latency balances, as well as some other reasons - you'll often be way below given 1.4x, even for AVX2, hardly expecting significant speed-ups. In order to make such access pattern really profitable, you need some extra (vectorized) computations with X[k] in loop body to amortize overhead (as opposed to just copying data from one place to another).

At the same time, there are **good news** as well. For short-term future **AVX-512** machines (KNL Xeon Phi, some future Xeon) vgather performance will likely change/improve, so that even simple data copy may give some extra speed-ups, but anyway this is not something you will observe on today' AVX/AVX2 machines.

Very last minor note: if you deal with sparse matrix (and that's why you tell about given indirect references), then possibly you may think of sparse-data compressed row storage format and as a result different SIMD trade-offs, although it's too far from original scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

In theory this is fine, but it depends on what processor you have. You need [vector gather](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions#Advanced_Vector_Extensions_2) functionality which was added to x86 processors through AVX2 and first appeared in the Haswell microarchitecture. The pseudocode would look something like this

```
vr1 := simd_load4(x)
vr2 := simd_load4(y)
vr3 := vr1 * 4; // multiply by the number of rows
vr4 := vr3 + vr2;
vr5 := simd_gather(base=&table, offsets=vr4)
simd_store(x, vr5)
```

The SSE/AVX version might look like this

```
__m128i vr1 = _mm_load_si128 (x);
__m128i vr2 = _mm_load_si128 (y);
__m128i vr3 = _mm_mul_epi32 (vr1, _mm_set1_epi32 (4));
__m128i vr4 = _mm_add_epi32 (vr3, vr2);
__m128i vr5 = _mm_i32gather_epi32 (table, vr4, 1);
_mm_store_si128 (x, vr5);
```

Comment: Use a left-shift, not a `mul`.  Much faster, even apart from not needing a vector with `4` in each element.

Comment: If the 2D array is allocated via say `int** table` and `table[i]=malloc`, then I guess we're out of luck?

Answer (score 0):

If you are copying adjacent memory cells, you can use memcpy() to copy a whole chunk of data. But since that's the the case here, no can do, you have to use the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done on ARM NEON via VTBL instruction.

NEON can process LUTs up to 32byte rather quickly.